# php variable as a value instead of a reference

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I'm not really sure how to ask this question which is why I think I can't find a suitable answer...

I have a simple function and inside that function I'm assigning an existing array to a variable. By changing the variable, I would like to update the array as well. I'm well aware that I can do it by pushing the variable data back out to the array but I'm curious if I can use this in a more simple fashion... almost as if I'm storing the variable as a value instead of a reference to the array.

Here's the function with my notes

```
function __construct($name, $action, $a){ # $a accepts a series of multidimensional sub-arrays
        $f = $this -> form; #passing the reference in here
        $f['name'] = $name; #ref 
        $f['action'] = $action; #ref 
        foreach($a as $k => $v){
            if(is_array($f[$k])){
                array_push($f[$k], $v);
            }else{
                $f[$k] = $v;
            }
        }
        # $f now contains a new value however I want to know if it's possible to make $f directly change $this -> form without a back reference
        $this -> form = $f; #this solves the problem but is there a better way?
        var_dump($this -> form);
    }
```

It shouldn't make much of a difference but here's $this -> form

```
protected $form = array(
        "title" => "",
        "name" => "",
        "id" => "",
        "class" => "Frm-cb", #default class for all forms
        "action" => "",
        "method" => "POST",
        "rel" => "",
        "topmsg" => "",
        "autocomplete" => "",
        "inputs" => array(),
        "buttons" => array(),
        "props" => array(),
        "attributes" => array()
    );
```

Just curious if it's possible - thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but it's not common. You can do this:

```
$f = &$this->form;
```

And remove this

```
$this->form = $f;
```

Detailed information at [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php).

Comment: Might not be common but good to have in my arsenal. Thank you

Comment: Always good to know what is possible, we never know when we'll need things :) Good luck!